# How can I allow loading sqlite extensions with a sqlalchemy engine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, spatialite

## Overview

I want to include sqlite extensions in sqlalchemy.

### Issues

When I try to load the extension I get a not authorized error.

### MVE

Setup engine

```py
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
extension = '/path/to/extension.dll'
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        'SELECT load_extension(:path)',
        path=extension
    ).fetchall()
```

### Error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) not authorized
[SQL: SELECT load_extension(:path)]
[parameters: {'path': '/path/to/extension.dll'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

### Known Alternative

The sqlite3 library's connection has the [`enable_load_extension`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.enable_load_extension) method. I cannot use sqlite3 because I am using sqlalchemy's ORM heavily. The sqlite3 method loads the extension without issue. Something similar to that method - but in sqlalchemy - would be ideal.

Comment: Are you able to load the extension in sqlite.exe?  I don't think SQLA imposes any authority restrictions

Comment: I have not tried that. One thing I didn't explicitly state is that I'm only using in-memory sqlite databases. Will sqlite load that extension each time in the in-memory dbs if I load it with the CLI first?

Comment: I don't know - I was thinking more about the permissions angle.

Comment: You could try creating a [handler for the "connect" event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.connect) and see if you can enable loading extensions there.

Comment: When trying to load it with the CLI (`.load ./extension.dll`) I am getting `Error: The specified module could not be found.` The file does exist at that path though.

Comment: @GordThompson I tried loading the extension during the connect handler but received the same `Not Authorized` error.

Comment: When I loaded the extension with the sqlite3 library it worked completely as expected, and I could use the contained functions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Gord Thompson's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830772/how-can-i-allow-loading-sqlite-extensions-with-a-sqlalchemy-engine#comment126935480_71830772) and [VPfB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869774/42659) for a similar [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48851097/42659), I was successfully able to enable the extension by attaching a handler for the "connect" event.

#### Ubuntu

```py
from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine, text


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

@event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
def receive_connect(connection, _):

    connection.enable_load_extension(True)
    connection.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');")
    connection.enable_load_extension(False)


with engine.connect() as connection:

    result = connection.execute(text("SELECT spatialite_version() as version;"))
    row = result.fetchone()
    print(f"Spatialite Version: {row['version']}")
```

#### Windows

The path to the folder containing the DLL file (`mod_spatialite.dll`) must be added in front of the PATH variable. Windows binaries for SpatiaLite can be downloaded from [gaia-gis.it](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html).

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine, text


SPATIALITE_PATH = r"C:\apps\mod_spatialite-5.0.1-win-amd64"

os.environ["PATH"] = f"{SPATIALITE_PATH};{os.environ['PATH']}"


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

@event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
def receive_connect(connection, _):

    connection.enable_load_extension(True)
    connection.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')")
    connection.enable_load_extension(False)


with engine.connect() as connection:

    result = connection.execute(text("SELECT spatialite_version() as version;"))
    row = result.fetchone()
    print(f"Spatialite Version: {row['version']}")
```